Gradle compiler is still targeting an older Java version despite having jdk17 installed and configured
I am on react-native 0.72.5. Openjdk version "17.0.13" on Ubuntu.
It was all working fine until I took an apk build. Ever since that the project fails to run on my device/emulator. It shows an error like this.
> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED


  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/home/trsuser/Desktop/Projects/Trois/HRMS-MOBILE/Hrms-app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/layoutReanimation/AnimationsManager.java:356: error: pattern matching in instanceof is not supported in -source 11
      if (props.get(Snapshot.TRANSFORM_MATRIX) instanceof ReadableNativeArray matrixArray) {
                                                                              ^
  (use -source 16 or higher to enable pattern matching in instanceof)
/home/trsuser/Desktop/Projects/Trois/HRMS-MOBILE/Hrms-app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java:440: error: switch rules are not supported in -source 11
      case "opacity" -> {
                     ^
  (use -source 14 or higher to enable switch rules)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

The issue boils down to React Native Reanimated requiring Java 16+ features while the Gradle compiler is still targeting an older Java version (-source 11). My Java version is correct (17), but my Gradle build isn't aligned with it.
Something related to this package is not right. I don't know how to fix this
app/build.gradle
android {
namespace "com.TroisHRMS"
ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

buildFeatures {
    buildConfig true
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.TroisHRMS"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 17
    versionName "1.1.7"
}
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}


 kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
        }


signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
     release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
        // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}

}
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",

The JDK version to build APK is not configured in Gradle above. If you are using Android Studio, you can change it at Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gralde. In the Gradle projects, change the Gradle JDK.
If you are using command line of Gradle, try to use org.gradle.java.home to specify the JDK, for example,
./gradlew assembleNationalDebug -Dorg.gradle.java.home=jdk_path

Hope it helps.
